# Getting Error when using API

Tags: javascript, json, api

I am new to APIs and they seem to keep hanging me up.  I keep getting the following error:

The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://null' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Here is my JS:

```
var url = "http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1";

$('#quotebutton').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax( {
      url: "http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1",
      success: function(data) {
        var post = data.shift(); // The data is an array of posts. Grab the first one.
        $('#quote-title').text(post.title);
        $('#quote').html(post.content);

        // If the Source is available, use it. Otherwise hide it.
        if (typeof post.custom_meta !== 'undefined' && typeof post.custom_meta.Source !== 'undefined') {
          $('#quote-source').html('Source:' + post.custom_meta.Source);
        } else {
          $('#quote-source').text('');
        }
      },
      cache: false
    });
  });
```

Comment: I just tried your url in a restles client and I get the error : "Sorry, you are not allowed to post on this site.". Looks like the POST request of http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts is actually trying to create a post. Please consult their API

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @moataz-elmasry the js function is fine, but the API have access restrictions.
Running a fiddle of the same code runs just fine:
https://jsfiddle.net/9gtbsp2e/1/

**I updated the link to use `https` to remove security errors*